# Docker Ubuntu with nginx, php-fpm and s3fs but s3fs does not work

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, nginx, docker, s3fs

Hi I can't connect to the S3 storage from amazon which nginx should use as root.

That means that I run in run.sh the s3fs command but the docker doesn't connect to the S3 storage where is a HTML file who should display through the nginx. Because when I go to localhost I see the "forbitten" error.

I get no error in the logs so I have no glue how I can fix that.

Do you have any idea how I can fix the problem?

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
MAINTAINER Corelike (Fabian Hahn) <docker@corelike.com>

# Variables
ENV S3_LOCATION=/www
ENV S3_IDENTITY=IDENT
ENV S3_CREDENTIAL=SECRET
ENV S3_BUCKET=BUCKETNAME

# Update ubuntu
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get dist-upgrade -y

#Install nginx, php-fpm and s3fs
RUN apt-get install -y nginx php-fpm php-mysql git wget automake autotools-dev g++ git libcurl4-gnutls-dev libfuse-dev libssl-dev libxml2-dev make pkg-config && git clone https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse && wget https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init/releases/download/v1.0.1/dumb-init_1.0.1_amd64.deb && dpkg -i dumb-init_*.deb && rm dumb-init_*.deb
WORKDIR s3fs-fuse
RUN ./autogen.sh && ./configure --prefix=/usr --with-openssl && make && make install
WORKDIR /

# Configuration PHP
RUN sed -i 's/;cgi.fix_pathinfo=1/cgi.fix_pathinfo=0/g' /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini

# Copy startup script
ADD files/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
ADD files/run.sh /

# Cleaning
RUN rm -rf /var/cache/*

RUN chmod 755 /run.sh && rm -rf /s3fs-fuse && mkdir /s3data

EXPOSE 80
VOLUME /www
CMD dumb-init /run.sh
```

and my run.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Get s3 creds from env var and write to password file
echo "$S3_IDENTITY":"$S3_CREDENTIAL" >> /etc/passwd-s3fs
chmod 600 /etc/passwd-s3fs
# Mount s3 bucket from environment variable
mkdir -p $S3_LOCATION
s3fs $S3_BUCKET $S3_LOCATION -o allow_other,mp_umask=022,use_cache=/tmp/s3cache,dbglevel=info -f

mkdir -p /logs/nginx
mkdir -p /tmp/nginx
chown www-data:www-data /tmp/nginx
chown -R www-data:www-data /logs
chown -R www-data:www-data /www

touch /www/text.txt

service php7.0-fpm start
nginx

# Keep it running
tail -f /dev/null
```

I start the docker with the following command:

```
sudo docker run -d -p 80:80 --privileged nginx
```

Thank you very much!

Best

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! When you say "can't connect", please provide the *specific* command you think is failing (even if you don't see an error message), what happened exactly, and what you expected to happen.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback I have added a better description.

Comment: Are you sure that nginx starts?  `s3fs -f` should run in the foreground so no other commands should execute.